# Is attendance to seminar worth mentioning in 500 words application?

Tags: application-cover-letter

In an application for an internship I am required to talk about the list of preferred projects.

One of these project is a generalization of the work I've seen being presented in my department and thought it was interesting (and I've somehow looked into this internship because I knew the author of the project).

Is it a good idea to mention it? I've also interacted with the speaker (whom I previously invited to speak at summer school and works in a field similar to mine).

I am unsure on whether it is something that is worth flagging or if I should focus on more concrete reasons for my interests given the short amount of space.

Comment: Your question title does not make much sense with regard to what you are asking here. Also you haven't said why you would rather refrain from doing this? I don't see the drawback.

Comment: Sorry, editing the title I cutted part of it and didn't notice. Fixed. Also, added my reasoning on why I'm asking.

Comment: "I had the chance to interact/discuss/work with Mr. X on topic Y and it was really interesting and enlightening." That's only 19 words, and it could be cut down farther if needed, so I don't see the problem if this is really an important point for you.